# How to convert a date to a number of days from 0001-01-01?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, date, datetime

How can I convert any date to just number of days? This is what I tried:

```
import datetime
import calendar


def leap_day_counter(yr):
    leap_days = 0
    # since 1582 11 days are missing
    if yr >= 1582:
        leap_days += 11
    for specific_year in range(1, yr):
        if calendar.isleap(specific_year):
            leap_days += 1
    return leap_days


def month_to_day(yr, mth):
    all_days = 0
    for specific_month in range(1, mth+1):
        days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(yr, specific_month)
        all_days += days_in_month[1]
    return all_days


date = datetime.datetime.now()
days_passed = ((date.year * 365) + leap_day_counter(date.year)) + month_to_day(date.year, date.month) + date.day
print(days_passed)
```

I got 737 158 days but according to https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html I should have 736 755 days. Do I miss something? Is there easier way to do this?

Comment: Did you know there are [11 days have gone missing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) since 1582? ... On second look: ah, your difference is quite a bit larger than that so it's not the only problem.

Comment: Numbers of days… from what? The beginning of the year? The year 1? Your birth day?

Comment: @ Didn't know about! Thanks for info! Why they are missing?

Comment: Because of the link in that comment.

Comment: @Mathias Ettinger Year 0

Comment: @Hsin [Year 0 does not exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero)

Comment: Since what date do you want to get the number of days? 0000-01-01 or what?

Comment: But 737147 - 365 - 11 is still 736771 so some 16 more days should be missing from somewhere

Comment: Let's go with year 1 then. Thanks for all comments I already learned good stuff

Comment: `year_one = datetime.datetime(1,1,1)` ; `(date-year_one).days` yields 736752. ^^

Comment: @Uvar So… adding 1 day to include the end date as well, there is still 2 days missing between this computation and the one from timeanddate.com. Any idea which ones?

Comment: @Hsin Also, it might be worth reading [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)

Comment: @MathiasEttinger interesting indeed!

Comment: @Mathias Ettinger Thanks! I will.

Answer (score 2):

This helps

```
from datetime import date

d0 = date(2000, 1, 01)
d1 = date.today()
delta = d1 - d0
print delta.days
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately we still miss 2 or 3 days if we will change date to 1,1,1 (I'm comparing to result here: https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?y1=1&m1=1&d1=1&y2=2018&m2=2&d2=28&ti=on )

Answer (score 1):

The number of days between two dates can be calculated as below: For more see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). Hope this may help

```
>>>enddate = "2018/03/12" +" 23:59"
>>>enddate = datetime.strptime(enddate, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
>>>(enddate-datetime.now()).days
12
```

Update:edit

```
>>>import datetime
>>>checkdate = datetime.datetime.strptime("0001-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
>>>days = (datetime.datetime.now()-checkdate).days
>>>days
   736757
```

2 days difference because start days and end date are excluded.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't want to calculate difference between two dates.

Comment: @Hsin have a look

Answer (score 1):

1. Are the amount of days in a year correct for you?

   01/01/0001 - 01/01/2018 has 736,696, you say there is 737,060. This is roughly 1 year too many.

   ```
   (date.year - 1) * 365
   ```
2. After fixing the above, we should check if 01/01/0001 - 01/02/2018 works.

   The website says 736,727, where you say 736,754. Which is about the entire month of February too many.

   ```
   for specific_month in range(1, mth)
   ```
3. You have one too many leap years.

   ```
   for specific_year in range(1, yr)
   ```

   You can also simplify this code to:

   ```
   def leap_day_counter(y):
       y -= 1
       return y//4 - y//100 + y//400
   ```

This is now the same as `datetime.datetime.now().toordinal()`.

Comment: Are you sure about months? We can check function with (print(month_to_day(1,1)) and instead of 31 we will get 0 I think that it is correct. I might be wrong though

Comment: I think we need to search for days elsewhere I learned that for example we lost 11 days in 1582 year I updated function in main question

Comment: I also learned that assuming that every 4th year is leap year is wrong (that's why I use calendar module)

Comment: No reason to get so aggresive